# How to subscribe to Azure Event Grid Topic using HTTP Webhook activity in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I have a scenario in which I want to use Azure Logic App / Azure Power App to use the `HTTP Webhook` activity to subscribe to Event Grid Topic. I have been using Azure Event Grid connector/activity to connect with Event Grid in the Logic App but now my manager wants to move from native connector to `HTTP Webhook` activity. Surprisingly I have been look into this but I could not find any resource online which demonstrate/suggest how HTTP Webhook activity can be used.

I tried to use the below flow but I am getting this error

`"Unauthorized","message":"The request authorization key is not authorized for EVENTGRIDNAME.NORTHEUROPE-1.EVENTGRID.AZURE.NET.`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Though I have'nt done this yet myself, my first guess is that you manually need to verify your Endpoint first.

As per Code you get an Event of type "`Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent`". In this Event is a `validationCode` included that you must send back to the EventGrid as Validation-Handshake.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/receive-events#endpoint-validation

As soon as this has happended your Endpoint is usually seen as Authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of using the **Http Webhook Trigger** for subscribing on the Azure Event Grid (AEG) Topic:

[image]

The **Http Webhook Trigger** has a responsibility to create an AEG subscription with a callback event handler destination endpoint during its subscribing process and also for deleting this subscription from the AEG (unsubscribing process).
Based on the [AEG REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/controlplane-version2021-12-01/event-subscriptions) in my example:

Subscribe - Method:

```
PUT
```

Subscribe - URI:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/mySubscription123?api-version=2021-12-01
```

Subscribe - Body:

```
  {
    "properties": {
      "destination": {
        "endpointType": "WebHook",
        "properties": {
          "endpointUrl": @{listCallbackUrl()}
          }
       }
   }
 }
```

Subscribe - Headers:

```
 Authorization  Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ....
```

Unsubscribe - Method:

```
DELETE
```

Unsubscribe - URI:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/mySubscription123?api-version=2021-12-01
```

Unsubscribe - Headers:

```
 Authorization  Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ....
```

Note, that the Authorization header is required for using the AEG REST APIs.

Also, I do recommend to read the following docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-webhook

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-api-app